# What is the difference between Grid and Matrix in SAP B1?

Tags: sapb1

When should I use a Matrix and when should I use a Grid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you want to work with UDOs, use matrix, otherwise use grid.

Some differences.

Matrix

- to load the data you need Dbdatasource
- effective for Udo's
- Filled automatically by SAP b1 when your navigate

Grid

- you can load the data using a SQL Query.
- Has Problems with columns of type double (you must use a workaround for this)
- you cannot modify udo data (just for viewing) - can't link to UDO
- you can create levels of visualitation (extend/collapse rows)
- grid is much faster with linking large ammount of data

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

In short:
Grid is faster in certain situations, but matrix is more versatile (at least in Sbo version 2007 and before).
Chech out the Sap SDN forums on https://www.sdn.sap.com/, they are big source of information.

Answer (score 0):

Gird is best used for display purpose. we can easily display huge data simply.  where as Matrix is best used for data maintaining purpose because it can be bonded with UDO where user can easily assess data screen level. No extra code can be written like grid evey thing will be handled by SAP object only.